# Debian - qcow2 lazy_refcounts

Tags: debian, kvm

I have just configured a debian 7.8 server with KVM and tried to preallocate a disk image with the following command:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,lazy_refcounts=on /home/stuart/vms/ubuntu.base.img 20G
```

This results in the following error:

```
Unknown option 'lazy_refcounts'
qemu-img: Invalid options for file format 'qcow2'.
```

Now when I run that command on an Ubuntu 14.04 KVM hypervisor, it works just fine, so I am guessing that my Qemu version is too old? The output of `qemu -version` is:

```
QEMU emulator version 1.1.2 (Debian 1.1.2+dfsg-6a+deb7u6), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

#### Question:

Do I need a later version of qemu to be able to take advantage of lazy refcounts, and if so does anybody know how I can grab a stable later version? Perhaps the command just needs to be written differently for debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy refcounts were added in [version 1.2](http://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/1.2), so the version you have is indeed too old to support that feature.

You can install a newer version from [Debian backports](https://backports.debian.org).

Comment: To install from backports, run `sudo echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list` and then `sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install "qemu-kvm" -y`